# Can I remove a Distribution Profile for an app already on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, distribution

I'm currently stuck in the distribution-profile-jungle and I can't find my way out.
I have launched an app to the App Store using my Distribution Profile, for various reasons I needed to wipe my keychain. When this was done I successfully updated the Development Profile by adding my newly created certificate. All is fine up until now.

The problem starts when I want to update the **Distribution** Profile to incorporate my new certificate. According to my experience this can not be done without removing it and creating a new one.

Question:

- If I do this what will happen to the app in the App Store? (Will users still be able to download it?)
- Can I still build the same app using the new Distribution Profile?

I am grateful for any knowledge/links which can clarify this issue.

Info:
 I'm using Snow Leopard 64-bit, XCode 3.2.2 and SDK 3.0.

Best regards //Abeansits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find documentation anywhere, but I've created new distribution certificates for Apps that are in the store without encountering any problems.

I believe that the distribution certificate is only used to verify your identity when transmitting the binary.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://www.softwareops.com/blogs/iPhone/iPhoneDevBlog_files/43ed56883b6bd4bb6f5a0ccf2b27bd59-13.html):

> An application that has placed items
>   into the Key Chain can’t retrieve
>   those items if a follow-on version is
>   signed with a different distribution
>   profile.